# Python: Please help me understand this scope issue

Tags: python, scope

Going from Javascript to Python really just means that scope is Satan reincarnated.

With this code, everything is fine:

```
a = 10

def elFunction():
    print a
    if (4 > 2):
        print a

elFunction()
```

With this code, I die a little inside

```
a = 10

def elFunction():
    a += 1
    if (4 > 2):
        print a

elFunction()
```

Why does this code draw an error?

Comment: You haven't declared `global a` in your function, so you can't modify it. See e.g. https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/global-statement.html

Comment: Weirdly, I felt the same way about going from Python to Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `a` a global variable:

```
a = 10

def elFunction():
    # Specify that a is global
    global a
    a += 1
    if (4 > 2):
        print a

elFunction()
```

This prints `11`